# FindInstance of Matrices

Tags: matrix, symbols

I'm trying to use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to find examples of matrices that complete an expression. However, it seems like I need to specify atomics as my variables to the function. So, here's a really simple example of what I'm trying to do.

A simple test condition could be that my d-dimensional matrix `lol` should be the identity matrix on those d dimensions. Here's some naive code that doesn't work

```
FindInstance[lol==IdentityMatrix[3],PopulateMatrix[lol,3]]
```

Where

```
PopulateMatrix[symbol_, dimension_] := 
 Flatten[Table[
   Table[symbol[[i, j]], {j, 1, dimension}], {i, 1, dimension}]]
```

I feel like this must be close to a correct solution, but it feels ugly. `PopulateMatrix[lol,3]` returns a desired list of expressions  `{lol[[1, 1]], lol[[1, 2]], lol[[2, 1]], lol[[2, 2]]}` that look like they should play nicely as variables for `FindInstance`, but it screams at me while doing so, saying that `lol[[2,1]]` is longer than the depth of the object, because I've not initialised `lol` as a matrix, but I don't know how to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `lol = Array[s, {3, 3}]; FindInstance[lol == IdentityMatrix[3], 
 Flatten@lol]`

Comment: This seems strange to me- why can we call upon s within array without mathematica complaining that s[[3,1]] doesn't exist, but I can't call upon lol[[3,1]] in FindInstance without setting it up?

Comment: I'm using `s[3,1]` ,not `s[[3,1]]` !!

Comment: Compare `Head[s[3, 1]]` with `Head[s[[3, 1]]]`

Comment: ah, awesome. thanks, I didn't immediately spot that subtlety